# Alternative to write \normalfont

Tags: fonts

When I use `\begin{lemma} .. \end{lemma}` I  should write `\normalfont` after `\begin{lemma}` to get normal font. Otherwise, content in lemma would be in italic font.

It is not comfortable to write `\normalfont` always. Is there any simpler way to make everything in lemma (and other places) in normal font with out writing this `\normalfont`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The standard document classes don't define `lemma`, so you must have loaded a package that defines it or defined it yourself. Can you tell us how you defined `lemma`? It should be possible to alter the definition such that the font is not switched to italics in the first place.

Comment: @moewe Please see edited file. I have added how I defined lemma

Comment: Unrelated note: You should load `hyperref` at the end of your preamble, there are a few packages which should be loaded afterwards (e.g. `cleveref`), but as a general rule of thumb this holds true.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks.. I did not knew how that affect the outcome. Please consider to write this in your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `\theoremstyle` prior to `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{section}` to `definition` which is a predefined style of `amsthm` that uses the non-italic Roman font (every `\newtheorem` after `\theoremstyle` will use that style, you can switch back to the italic style with `\theoremstyle{plain}`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\usepackage{color}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
  This is a lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
  This is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, you are saying if I write \theoremstyle{definition} before every \newtheorem I define, everything will be in normal font.. Is that correct?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik `\theoremstyle` acts as a switch, every `\newtheorem` after `\theoremstyle` will use that style, `amsthm` comes with 3 predefined styles, `plain`, `definition`, `remark`, `plain` is the default one, `definition` is similar but uses an upright font, `remark` uses an upright font and less vertical spacing around it.

Comment: I am slightly confused.. You are saying plain is the default one so, it should give non italic font right? wHat am I missing :O

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik As it turns out `plain` isn't actually *plain* in the usual sense of the word here. Have a look at §4.1 *The `\theoremstyle` command* of [the `amsthm` documentation (`amsthdoc`)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf), which explains that `plain` means "italic text, extra space above and below".

Comment: @moewe Oh Ok Ok :) Thank you :) I will read